# Duplicate strings in nested lists

Tags: python, list

Set up - I have a list with nested lists (call it relay sets) that looks something like this:

```
relay_sets = [
    [[80100, 'a']], 
    [[75000, 'b']], 
    [[64555, 'c']], 
    [[55000, 'd'], [44000, 'e']], 
    [[39000, 'f'], [2000, 'g']], 
    [[2000, 'h'], [999, 'i'], [999, 'j']], 
    [[999, 'k'], [999, 'l'], [343, 'm']]
]
```

A user is put in to one of the relay sets (with uniform probability) and then again uses one of the nested lists in the sublist with equal probability. So for example a user has a 1/7 chance of being put in `[[80100, 'a']]` but then is guaranteed to use `[80100, 'a']`, whereas a user has 1/7 chance of being put in `[[55000, 'd'], [44000, 'e']]` and then has a 1/2 chance of using `[55000, 'd']`.

I wrote a script that finds the probability of using a certain relay:

```
def prob_using_relay(relay, relaysets):
  prob1 = 1 / float(len(relaysets))
  for index, item in enumerate(relaysets):
    for i in item:
      if relay in i:
        num_relays_in_set = len(relaysets[index])
        prob2 = 1 / float(num_relays_in_set)
  total_prob = float(prob1 * prob2)
  return total_prob

print prob_using_relay(80100, relay_sets) # gives correct answer of 0.142857142857
```

My problem is I don't know how to account for duplicates. So if I wanted to know the chance of using a relay with 999 bandwidth the answer should be `(2/3 * 1/7 + 2/3 * 1/7)` but my script gives `1/21`. Or if I wanted to know the chance of using a relay with 2000 bandwidth the answer should be `(1/2 * 1/7 + 1/3 * 1/7)` instead of `(1/2 * 1/7)`.

Could anyone help with altering my function to account for duplicates?

Comment: Sum your probabilities. You're setting it instead.

Comment: from where comes `num_guards_in_set`?

Comment: sorry i edited my script for the purposes of the question but missed a line.

Comment: i think `num_guards_in_set` must be `num_relays_in_set`

Comment: @RaydelMiranda His formula is right. 999 appears 4 times in the numerator. In yours it appears 8 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems with your code. You are doing useless casts to floats. Another being that it can't handle probabilities more than 2 levels deep. Here's a recursive approach which can handle this:

```
relay_sets = [
    [[80100, 'a']],
    [[75000, 'b']],
    [[64555, 'c']],
    [[55000, 'd'], [44000, 'e']],
    [[39000, 'f'], [2000, 'g']],
    [[2000, 'h'], [999, 'i'], [999, 'j']],
    [[999, 'k'], [999, 'l'], [343, 'm']]
]

def prob_using_relay(relay, relaysets):
    if isinstance(relaysets[0], int):
        return int(relaysets[0] == relay)
    return sum(prob_using_relay(relay, relayset) for relayset in relaysets) / len(relaysets)

print(prob_using_relay(80100, relay_sets))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def prob(bandwidth, relaysets):
    answer = 0.0
    for subl in relaysets:
        answer += sum(1.0 for r in subl if r[0] == bandwidth)/len(subl)
    return answer/len(relaysets)
```

Output:

```
In [44]: prob(999, relay_sets)
Out[44]: 0.19047619047619047

In [45]: 4/21
Out[45]: 0.19047619047619047
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use Fractions:

> ```
> from fractions import Fraction
>
> def prob_using_relay(relay, relaysets):
>      prob = Fraction(0,1)
>      for set in relaysets:
>        if isinstance(set, list) and relay in set:
>            prob += Fraction(1, len(relaysets))
>        elif isinstance(set, list):
>            prob += Fraction(1, len(relaysets)) * prob_using_relay(relay, set)           
>      return prob
>
> prob_using_relay(999, relay_sets)
> Out: Fraction(4, 21)
> ```